# If $G$ has no proper subgroups other than the trivial group,then $G$ is a finite group.

Tags: abstract-algebra

If $G$ has no proper subgroups other than the trivial group,then show that $G$ is a finite group.

---

totally stuck.can I get some help

Comment: $G$ is actually finite of prime order ( or itself trivial).

Answer (score 2):

Assume $G$ is infinite and $1\ne g\in G$. Then $\langle g\rangle$ is either a proper subgroup, or one has $G=\langle g\rangle\cong \mathbb Z$, which has the proper subgroup $2\mathbb Z$

Answer (score -1):

See the subgroup generated by an element of $G$.